# ApexCharts Donut Chart legend titles not reflecting provided data labels (stuck as 'series-1' etc.)

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I'm importing Apexcharts' simple donut chart to my Vue.js project, however, even after following the documentation provided on their [site](https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/), the legend titles stay as 'series-1, series-2, ...'.

Here's a picture of what's rendered: [Donut Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z242K.png)

As you can see I'm following the documentation, adding `series` and `labels` to both the data object and the `div` element, but for some reason still can't render the proper labels.

How would I go about resolving this issue?

Side note: switching `legend.show` from false to true does nothing.

```
<div id="donut-chart">

    <v-container>
        <div id="chart">
            <apexchart 
                type=donut 
                width=380 
                :options="chartOptions" 
                :labels="labels" 
                :series="series" />
        </div>
    </v-container>

</div>

import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'

export default {
    name: 'donut-chart',
    data: () => ({
        series: [23, 11, 54, 72, 12],
        labels: ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Papaya", "Orange"],
        chartOptions: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 480,
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        width: 200
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false
                    }
                }
            }],
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                offsetY: 0,
                height: 230
            }
        }
    }),
    components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`labels` property should be a nested property of `chartOptions`, not to be passed as a separate prop.

```
chartOptions: {
  labels: ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Papaya", "Orange"],
  dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
  },
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 480,
      options: {
          chart: {
              width: 200
          },
          legend: {
              show: false
          }
      }
  }],
  legend: {
      position: 'right',
      offsetY: 0,
      height: 230
  }
}


<apexchart 
  type=donut 
  width=380 
  :options="chartOptions" 
  :series="series" />
```

Comment: Also, Its worked for React JS. Thank you.